# Could someone reccomend any good books to start with machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, references

I have no experience, so something simple, yet effective would be perfect.

Comment: This is very broad. Could you please edit the post to indicate some directions of interest and application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Introduction to Statistical Learning is a good book to start with. It requires minimal statistical and programming knowledge and written in a simple language, nevertheless, it goes deep into all models that are covered.